# Connecting Angularjs to Spring RESTFul service using AngularJS $http service

Tags: angularjs, spring-restcontroller

This is the Spring Rest controller in the back end which simply get all the student in the list. I have tested it and works fine.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("a/rest")
public class RestfulController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentDao studentDao;
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Student>> index() {
        ResponseEntity<List<Student>> studList = new ResponseEntity<List<Student>>( studentDao.getAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
        return studList;
    }
}
```

This is what i am trying to do i want that list of student to display in the paragraph with id defined(id="displayData")

I have created button that loads the function showData()

Then i am trying to implement $http service of Angularjs for connecting to the back in this way

```
<body>

<input type="button" value="Get Data" onclick="showData()" />
<p id="displayData" />

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

function showData() {
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'a/rest'
}).then(function (response) {

    $('#displayData').html(JSON.stringify(response));

  });

}
</script>
```

Here i need help..!! Problem is on the frontend. How can i implement $http service that works file?

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @Praveen : i have to display that  data in the <p id="displayData" /> but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$http response will contain

[image: $http response json]

properties. $http response.data contain actual json data. It does not work the way jquery(`$.ajax()`) work.
You need to bootstrap your angular application before you can use `$http` service.

Below is minimal example suit to your need.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="studApp" ng-controller="StudController">

    <input type="button" value="Get Data" ng-click="showData()" />
    <p id="displayData" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('studApp', [])
        .controller('StudController', function($http, $scope) {
          $scope.showData = function() {
            $http({
              method : 'GET',
              url : 'a/rest'
            }).then(function(response) {
              $('#displayData').html(JSON.stringify(response.data));
            });
          }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

$('#displayData').html(JSON.stringify(response.data));

server side return data is JSON string?

Comment: Server is returning JSON data, JSON.stringify(respose) is used to convert it to string and $('#displayData').html is used to put that string data in the <p id="displayData" />. Your code didn't worked too. You can share if you have similar implementation before?

Comment: try  change then to success